Change the start pinned icon for Windows Store apps in Windows 11
I know that you can't officially change Microsoft Store apps icons and it's very frustrating.
I was able to find this solution, but it only works for the shortcuts that are pinned on the taskbar.
How can I change an app icon to be visible globally, not only in the taskbar? How can I change the icon to be visible on the star menu as well, or how do I add an app to the start menu with the icon changed?
Thanks.
